# Spring Boot 2: some static resources are not loaded

Tags: javascript, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf, static-resource

I added static resources into `/static/` path in spring boot application.

```
/static/
   /css/
   /images/
   /js/
```

When page loaded some `css` and `js` files are not loaded. For example: `/static/js/jquery-ui/css/no-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css` loaded, but, `/static/js/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.minimal.min.js` and `/static/css/font-icons/entypo/css/entypo.css` resources are not loaded - returned 404. If I move these resources to 1 or 2 step upward in folder tree, theese resources get reachable, so I can download them with direct url. but I don't want to do this. Because they are part of some template and moving can damage theme structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied not loaded files to same folder with different name.

```
/static/css/font-icons/entypo/css/
    entypo.css
    entypo_1.css
```

After, deleted old version and renamed new copy as old version. I don't know why, but after doing this operation for all not loaded resources they are loaded. Now its work for me.

**EDITED**

It need to be cleaned and built project in such situations.

This problem occurred again when I run project without building after checking out project to another PC from SVN. Then I cleaned and built project and run. The problem did not occur after that

Comment: Why you just don't put in css folder  .....in this way /static/css/entypo.css,entypo_1.css

Comment: because it is a part of template and other resources use it with relative path. There have more resources. I cannot check which resource use it which not.

Comment: Yes I have. I think cleaning and rebuilding also may solution of problem.

Comment: As you have solved the problem but you need to reproduce same scenerio again if  it still exist then cleaning and rebuilding might not be solution

Comment: Now I have no problem. And I don't know what was the reason. I just suggested cleaning and rebuilding. Because, as the result, logically I did not change anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174638/discussion-between-this-is-om-vm-and-ulphat).